# Is there a way to assign default values to properties that vary based on each user in ASP.NET 7.0 Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I have been wondering for a few hours if there is any way to create a default value for a property that will be different for each user ?
Perhaps I need a fresh look, because I feel like I'm going around in circles and not finding a solution.

[A preview of a form for a search engine sending GET requests from razor pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQAAD.png)

My problem I am looking for a solution to:

Each user would have his default value defined, which would be stored in the database, and when the GET request is called, the default value would be assigned to the parameter, unless the user assigned another value in a field in the form, or sent the form with an empty tags field .
Razor Page. dot net 7

My code:

```
public string? Tags { get => GetDefaultVaulePerUser(); set => GetDefaultVaulePerUser(); }


public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string searchString, string dateFrom, string dateTo, string currentSort, Status status, string tags/* = default value per users*/, string szansa="Średnia", bool czyMalejaco = false, int strona = 1)
        {

        }
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

assigning a value to the Tags property requires a static value:
public string? Tags { get; set; } = "Default value per users";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways I can think to do this but the only way I could see having some already set value for a user is if you store it with the user object. Are you using OAuth where you can add a custom value to the scope? Are you using local aspnet authentication where you can add property to the User that you'll have access to? If none of those are options then you have to call the database to get the values and you would do that in the method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string searchString, string dateFrom, string dateTo, string currentSort, Status status, string tags, string szansa="Średnia", bool czyMalejaco = false, int strona = 1, bool userDefinedTags = false)
{
   // Updated using your comment code.
   if (!userDefinedTags) {
     var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
     Tags = (user is null) ? string.Empty : user.DefaultTags;
   }
   return Page();
}
```

Comment: I need to retrieve the user object from the database and refer to the DefaultTags field.         var uzytkownik =  await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (uzytkownik != null)
            {
                return myDefaultTags =  uzytkownik.DefaultTags;
            }                                                                                                                                     
But I also have to take into account the scenario that the user may want to send an empty tags field in the get request.

Comment: Updated my answer using your get user code.

Comment: I didn't see the last sentence. My suggestion for that would to be add another parameter as a flag to determine if the user is the one who set tags to an empty string or not.  `bool userDefinedTags = false` If they change the tag values then the flag would be true.

Comment: @Stephan Gilboy well yes, but if I pass an empty tags field in the form, then when I enter the OnGet method the if is null or empty condition is true and I retrieve and overwrite the empty field from scratch by assigning the value from the database to the tags property.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are doing your queries, do you actually need to get the default values or can you build them into your query?

Consider the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetData
@tags varchar(255) = NULL,
@userID int
--other params
AS
BEGIN

IF @tags IS NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT @tags = DefaultTags
  FROM Users
  WHERE UserID = @userID
END

-- do whatever select you need to do here

END
```

Then if the user passes a tag through, you would pass that to the stored procedure. If the user does not pass a tag then you do not pass a value to the stored procedure, so it takes the default `NULL` value and goes off and queries the default value.

Comment: The idea to get around the problem from the base side is interesting - in fact, I did not consider this possibility - but all the time I have to keep in mind that the user may want to pass an empty value in the form. Ok, as Stephan Gilboy suggested I can use another helper variable: bool userDefinedTags = false, but when to assign it the value true .... ?

Comment: In the C#? Could you just do, `bool userDefinedTags = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tags)`? If no tags are passed then `tags = null`, or if `tags = "" or " "`, this will be `false`, otherwise it should return `true`?

Comment: yes c#.
Performing a search request by clicking on the "Search" button, I can set the flag userDefinedTags = false; Otherwise, in the GET request, I can pass userDefinedTags = True;
That should do the trick - I'll test it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stephen Gilboy - your suggestion guided me to the solution.
By triggering a GET request when the search button is pressed, I set the false flag for the userDefinedTags helper variable, which is true by default. This takes care of the problem. Thanks again for your suggestions and help.

```
public bool UserDefinedTags { get; set; } = true;
(,,,)

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string searchString, string dateFrom, string dateTo, string currentSort, Status status, string tags, string szansa="Średnia", bool czyMalejaco = false, int strona = 1, bool userDefinedTags = false)
{
     var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
     tags = (user is null) ? string.Empty : !userDefinedTags ? tags : user.DefaultTags;
   return Page();
}
```